# Hiding show view toolbar in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to remove this toolbar shown in the image. I have tried disabling all other items in the toolbar but this one doesn't seem to go. This toolbar is blocking my editor's space and I want to get rid of it. Please tell me a way to remove this.

Thanks

[image: eclipse]

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try writing your own WorbenchWindow or WorkbenchPage (not sure exactly which right now) and overwrite maybe createWindowContents.
See this from [here](http://book.javanb.com/eclipse-rich-client-platform-designing-coding-and-packaging-java-applications-oct-2005/ch18lev1sec2.html) (i got this quote from there, but maybe you can find a book or better reference for this):

> There are limitations as to when you can override the Workbench
>   window. The Workbench's default implementation of
>   createWindowContents() creates controls that are not available to
>   clients, such as the job progress area, the trim that docks fast
>   views, and the perspective bar. When you override
>   createWindowContents(), you lose these areas.

Comment: Well frankly, I have never heard those two terms, isn't there any easier solution? btw does this toolbar come with eclipse by default, bcoz I think many ppl dont have this toolbar.

Comment: See my updated answer please. Sometimes (a lot of times :) ) removing default stuff is not really easy.

Comment: ya but I was trying to ask that if I reinstall eclipse, will this toolbar be gone ?

Comment: I don't know by heart :) try - but it will most likely only be gone if you are on the start page; if you are in an active editor, you will most likely have the button there.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of removing it. I have tried finding solutions but it isn't customizable

Comment: but when I had first installed eclipse, this toolbar wasn't there, so there must be some way to remove this, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey looks like they solved this issue in eclipse juno .. just download juno and life is good !

Answer (score 0):

Which version of eclipse you are using?You can toggle the toolbar visibility by clicking Window->Hide Toolbar or Window->Show toolbar